# Fastest way to determine constrained sum of an array

Tags: algorithms, complexity-theory, search-algorithms

I have two $N$-vectors of positive integers, called `cost` and `gain`, and I have another integer called `budget`. You can think of every pairwise correspondence between `cost` and `gain` as a stock, and every possible subset of stocks as a portfolio.

I need to determine the portfolio (subset of pairwise correspondences) whose sum of gains is maximised, given that the corresponding sum of costs is smaller than `budget`. Every stock can appear only once in the portfolio.

Example:

```
budget = 5, cost = [1,2,17,4], gain = [5,9,100,2]
```

The third element must be discarded because it doesn't fit in the budget, while the best subset is given by first plus second, because the cumulative gain would be 14 for an expense of 3, while the other subset first plus fourth would respect the budget but gain less.

I approached the problem thinking to extract all the subsets contained in the power set of integers from 1 to N with at least one element, that is, all the ordered sequences of indices from 1 to N with length varying from 1 to N. This would correspond to all the possible portfolios, let's say. However, it turned to be too slow, because of nested loops.

I feel like this must be some classical problem in Algorithms, but I never studied this subject and I have just the sensation that there must be some kind of Dynamical Programming like solution. What is the fastest solution to this problem?

Comment: Look for the "Knapsack Problem" which is exactly what you are dealing with.

Comment: That was it @Tassle, thank you